# I cannot change the image in pictureBox1 from code in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reference, static

First things first: Im pretty new to Programming, and I'm trying to learn the C# Language

My Goal: Having a method that changes the picture in pictureBox1.

Issue: I get the error that tells me that an object reference is required for non-static field.

Here's a snippet of my class where the method should go.

```
private class Execute
{
    private void valueChecker(char value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= charLenght; i++)
        {
            if (value != CharArray[i])
            {
                i++;
            }

            else if (value == CharArray[i])
            {
                CorrectLetter(value);
                svalue = true;
            }
        }
        if (svalue == true)
        {
            /* This is where the command is happening.
             But I get error message : "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property."
            */

            pictureBox1.Image = photos[x];
            x++;
        }
    }

}
```

I have also tried making new classes and methods other places in the code, and call it from the if statement, but I don't get this to work.

I need to change the picture in pictureBox1 if the svalue == true

A little further info on what exactly Im doing:
Im making a hangman game as an exercise, and I want to update the Image in pictureBox1 if the input letter can't be found in the answer.

The pictures are stored in an array I have called photos[].

Comment: If this is exactly the code, it doesn't make sense. The error only happens when you try to access non-static members in a static method.

Comment: Actually you can get that error if you place `Execute` *inside* the form class that has that picturebox as well.

Comment: `pictureBox1.Image ` where does this come from? Is it a property of your class `Execute` ? Do you call your method like this: `Execute.valueChecker('q')` ?

Comment: Your class need a reference to the PictureBox. Youi can add a Property and set it after creating an instance of the class or even pass it right into the constructor..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  method declaration should be something like this:

```
public void valueChecker(char value,PictureBox pictureBox1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This fixed the error and it also gave me a clue towards understanding how the compiler works.

Comment: The keywords here are 'references' and  'scope'.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var MyImage = new Bitmap(photos[x]);
 pictureBox1.Image = (Image) MyImage ;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs a **reference** to the `PictureBox`. You can add a **property** and set it after creating an instance of the class or even pass it right into the constructor..

```
private class Execute
{
   public PictureBox pBox {get; set;}

   public Execute(PictureBox  pb)
   {
        pBox  = pb;
   }

   private void valueChecker(char value)  // or maybe public ?!
   {
      ...
      ...

      if (pBox != null) pBox.Image = photos[x];
      x++;
    }
}
```

Create the class instance like this:

```
Execute someName = new Execute(pictureBox1);
```

Note that there are other ways to solve this; this is just a rather direct and straightforward one. If your class is a kind of service class you may want to go with Tarek's even more direct solution. Note that he not just adds the `PictureBox` to the parameter list. He also makes the function `public`.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I didn't try to write the code as you answered because Tarek's Solution worked. But I will save your answer for future reference.